# conditions and singular output

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
i = int(input("Enter an integer "))

if i%3 == 0: 
    print('Fizz')

if i%5 == 0:
    print('Buzz')

if i%3 == 0 and i%5 == 0:
    print('Fizz Buzz')
```

When I enter the integer "15", the program returns "Fizz", "Buzz", and "Fizz Buzz".
I'd like to seek some ideas as to how I get the program to return only one output base on the conditions.

No solutions!

Comment: Are you aware of `else`?

Comment: @Ryan I will look into it. This should work well.

Comment: @gorgamite this is python. I would use an else statement.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: @StephenRauch I've used one `if`, two `elif` and one `else` which provides the desirable output

Answer (score 1):

else statement is your friend.

Solution is removed :)